# Expectation of new measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

Fix probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$, let $D$ be a nonnegative random variable with $E[D] = 1$. Define a new probability measure $Q$ on $(\Omega, F)$ by $$Q[A] := E[D 1_A]$$
I have the following result and I don't see where does it come from : the expectation of a random variable $X$ with respect to $Q$ is given by
$$E_Q[X]=E_P[DX] $$

If $X$ and $D$ are discrete random variables, then $$E_Q[X]=\sum x Q(X=x)=\sum x E(D 1_{X=x}) = \sum x \sum y P(D=y \cap X=x) $$
which I struggle to make it equal to $E_P[DX]$.
Therefore, I tried the other way letting $$E_P[DX]= \sum i P(DX=i) = \sum i \sum  P(X=j \cap D=\frac ij ) $$
which is also still a bit far from the desired result. Is there a way out ?

Comment: There should be some conditions imposed on $X$. With suitable conditions, the two expectations will be equal to $\sum_i \sum_j ij P(D=i,X=j)$ your last line should change a bit to look like it

Comment: If $Q$ is defined by $Q(A) = \int_A D dP$ then $\int f dQ = \int f D dP$, this follows in the usual manner, indicator functions, simple functions and the rest using DCT.

Comment: Also look up Radon Nikodym derivatives. Here $D$ is the Radon Nikodym derivative of $Q$ wrt $P$, i.e. $\frac{dQ}{dP}=D$.

Comment: See [proposition 4.1](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/4-04-rn.pdf).